# Multiclient and server commandline argument issues

Tags: c, server, client

I have code for a server that can handle multiple clients. The client program can connect to the server and issue Unix commands such as ls, date, clear, etc. I have two problems that I cannot figure out. 1) When I initially type ls as an argument it will return some weird garbage, and then if I do ls again then it starts working properly. So only in the beginning, it will give me garbage. 2) When I type the argument 'ps -ael' into the terminal, it will work properly, but then after that I get a 'Failed' message, which is coming from the Client code, specifically at the while(1) loop where `if (send(clientSocket, s, echolen, 0) != echolen)`, this is where the error is occurring. I was curious to know if someone could point to what the problem could be, I think it might be because I create a char array that's too big but I'm not sure.

Client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 4444
#define BUFFSIZE 2048

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int clientSocket, ret, portnum;
struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
int received = 0;
unsigned int echolen;
char buffer[1024];

if(argc < 3){
    fprintf(stderr,"usage %s <server-ip-addr> <server-port>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(0);
}

portnum = atoi(argv[2]);


clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(clientSocket < 0){
    printf("Error in connection.\n");
    exit(1);
}
printf("Client Socket is created.\n");

memset(&serverAddr, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr));
// memset(&buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));
// serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
// serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
// serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

// bzero((char *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
if(!inet_aton(argv[1], &serverAddr.sin_addr)){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error invalid server IP address\n");
    exit(1);
}

serverAddr.sin_port = htons(portnum);

ret = connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
if(ret < 0){
    printf("Error in connection.\n");
    exit(1);
}
printf("Connected to server.\n");

char s[100];

while(1){
    fgets(s, 100, stdin);
    s[strlen(s)-1]='\0';
    echolen = strlen(s);
    /*  send() from client; */
    if (send(clientSocket, s, echolen, 0) != echolen) 
    {
        printf("Failed");
    }
    if(strcmp(s,"exit") == 0) // check if exit is typed
    exit(0);
    fprintf(stdout, "Message from server: ");
    while (received < echolen) 
    {
        int bytes = 0;
        /* recv() from server; */
        if ((bytes = recv(clientSocket, buffer, echolen, 0)) < 1) 
        {
            printf("Failed to get Information");
        }
        received += bytes;
        buffer[bytes] = '\0';

        fprintf(stdout, buffer);
    }
    int bytes = 0;

    do {
        buffer[bytes] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
    } while((bytes = recv(clientSocket, buffer, BUFFSIZE-1, 0))>=BUFFSIZE-1);
    buffer[bytes] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    printf("\n");

}
}
```

Server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 4444
#define BUFFSIZE 2048
#define MAX 2048

void setup(char inputBuffer[], char *args[], int *background){
const char s[4] = " \t\n";
char *token;
token = strtok(inputBuffer, s);
int i = 0;
while(token != NULL){
    args[i] = token;
    i++;
    token = strtok(NULL, s);
}
args[i] = NULL;
}

void HandleClient(int sock){
char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
int received = -1;
char data[MAX];
memset(data, 0, MAX);

while(1){
    data[0] = '\0';
    if((received = recv(sock, buffer, BUFFSIZE, 0)) < 0){
        printf("Error");
    }

    buffer[received] = '\0';

    strcat(data, buffer);
    if(strcmp(data, "exit") == 0){
        exit(0);
    }

    puts(data);
    char *args[100];
    setup(data, args, 0);
    int pipefd[2], length;

    if(pipe(pipefd)){
        printf("failed to create pipe");
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();
    char path[MAX];

    if(pid==0)
    {
        close(pipefd[0]); // close the readonly side of the pipe
        //close(1); // close the original stdout
        dup2(pipefd[1],1); // duplicate pipfd[1] to stdout
        dup2(pipefd[1], fileno(stderr));
        //close(pipefd[0]); // close the readonly side of the pipe
        close(pipefd[1]); // close the original write side of the pipe
        printf("before execvp");
        execvp(args[0],args); // finally execute the command
        // exit(0);
    }
    else
        if(pid>0)
        {
            close(pipefd[1]);
            memset(path,'\0',MAX);
            while(length=read(pipefd[0],path,MAX-1)){
                //printf("Data read so far %s\n", path);
                if(send(sock,path,strlen(path),0) != strlen(path) ){
                    printf("Failed");
                }
                fflush(NULL);
                //printf("Data sent so far %s\n", path);
            memset(path,0,MAX);
            }
            close(pipefd[0]);

            //exit(1); removed so server will not terminate
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error !\n");
            exit(0);//
        }

}
}

int main(){

int sockfd, ret;
struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;

int newSocket;
struct sockaddr_in newAddr;

socklen_t addr_size;

char buffer[1024];
pid_t childpid;

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(sockfd < 0){
    printf("Error in connection.\n");
    exit(1);
}
printf("Server Socket is created.\n");

memset(&serverAddr, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr));
serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

ret = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
if(ret < 0){
    printf("Error in binding");
    exit(1);
}
printf("Bind to port %d\n", 4444);

if(listen(sockfd, 10) == 0){
    printf("Listening....\n");
}else{
    printf("Error in binding.\n");
}

while(1){
    newSocket = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &newAddr, &addr_size);
    if(newSocket < 0){
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Connection accepted from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(newAddr.sin_addr), ntohs(newAddr.sin_port));

    //worker
    if((childpid = fork()) == 0){
        close(sockfd);

        while(1){
            recv(newSocket, buffer, 1024, 0);
            if(strcmp(buffer, ":exit") == 0){
                printf("Disconnected from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(newAddr.sin_addr), ntohs(newAddr.sin_port));
                break;
            }else{
                printf("Client: %s\n", buffer);
                send(newSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
                bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            }
            HandleClient(newSocket);
        }
    }
}


close(newSocket);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think `buffer[-1] = '\0';` is going to do?

Comment: If/when BUFFSIZE and MAX diverge, you're going to have problems.

Comment: `char buffer[1024];` should use `BUFFSIZE` and you should verify that all of your indexes into`buffer` are within limits.

Comment: Clean your user input. Your client is prone to goofy behavior when control codes are embedded in the string or the user enters more than 100 characters before hitting return. Passing some control codes through to your message passing code could cause problems. Actually, same applies to your client side. Scrub all message data.

Comment: On your client side, you're overwriting data received on earlier iterations through the loop. You need to adjust the `recv` output buffer and the allowed number of bytes to read as data accumulates.

Comment: Loop conditional is wrong: `while((bytes = recv(clientSocket, buffer, BUFFSIZE-1, 0))>=BUFFSIZE-1);`, `recv` will never return more than number of bytes asked for.

Comment: `buffer[bytes] = '\0';` same as my first comment, what if bytes is negative?

Comment: `recv` result type is `ssize_t` not `int`.

Comment: Compile with `-Wall` and fix your code to eliminate all warnings.